# How to search the data displayed on TextView dynamically in android?

Tags: android, listview, search

I am having a problem in searching a ListView. In my activity I have displayed some data in a list, Now I have a search bar on top of that list. I wanted to implement that when I type in the search bar the data in the listview should adjust according to the search results. I have used TextWatcher but the problem is the ArrayList from which I am populating the data in the list view is of custom type.

This is the custom type.

```
public class FRNews {

// Private Members START
        private long id  = 0;
        private String headline = "";
        private String detail = "";
        private String submit_date = Configuration.DEFAULT_DATE;

//Private Members END


// Getter/Setter START
        public void setId(long id){
            this.id = id ;
        }

        public void setHeadline(String headline){
            this.headline = headline ;
        }

        public void setDetail(String detail){
            this.detail = detail;
        }

        public void setSubmitDate(String submit_date){
            this.submit_date = submit_date;
        }

        public long getId(){
            return this.id ;
        }

        public String getHeadline(){
            return this.headline ;
        }

        public String getDetail(){
            return this.detail;
        }

        public String getSubmitDate(){
            return this.submit_date;
        }

// Getter/Setter END        

}
```

This is my class, which is calling the array adapter and is searching the listview using TextWatcher.

```
public class FRNewsList extends ListActivity {
    public static ArrayList<FRNews> newsList = new ArrayList<FRNews>();
    public static ArrayList<FRNews> tempList = new ArrayList<FRNews>();

    private int detailId = 0;
    private ProgressDialog progDialog;
    private FRCustomAdapterLatestNews newsAdapter;

    private ListView listView;
    private EditText etSearch;

    private TextView tvSeeAllNews;

    private String headline;

    int textLength = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.tab_home_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_search_news);

        tvSeeAllNews = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_news_see_all);

        if (newsList == null) {
            newsList = new ArrayList<FRNews>();
        }
        if (tempList == null) {
            tempList = new ArrayList<FRNews>();
        }

        putNewsInView();

        // listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<FRNews>(this,
        // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tempList));

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                setDetailId(position);

                int newsId = getDetailId();

                Intent i = new Intent(FRNewsList.this,
                        FRLatestNewsDetailActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id", newsId);

                // Create the view using FirstGroup's LocalActivityManager
                View v = FRNewsDetailActivityGroup.group
                        .getLocalActivityManager()
                        .startActivity("news_detail",
                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                        .getDecorView();

                // Again, replace the view
                FRNewsDetailActivityGroup.group.replaceView(v);

            }
        });

        etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                getNewsDbContent();
                textLength = count;
                tempList.clear();
                // int a = newsList.size();
                if (s.length() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < newsList.size(); i++) {
                        FRNews searchNews = newsList.get(i);
                        String headlineSearch = searchNews.getHeadline();
                        if (textLength <= headlineSearch.length()) {
                            if (etSearch
                                    .getText()
                                    .toString()
                                    .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                            (String) headlineSearch
                                                    .subSequence(0, textLength))) {
                                tempList.add(i, searchNews);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<FRNews>(
                            FRNewsList.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tempList));
                } else
                    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<FRNews>(
                            FRNewsList.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newsList));
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        tvSeeAllNews.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(FRNewsList.this, FRAllNews.class);

                // Create the view using FirstGroup's LocalActivityManager
                View view = FRNewsDetailActivityGroup.group
                        .getLocalActivityManager()
                        .startActivity("news_all",
                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                        .getDecorView();

                // Again, replace the view
                FRNewsDetailActivityGroup.group.replaceView(view);
            }
        });
    }

    private void putNewsInView() {
        // public void run() {
        getNewsDbContent();
        newsAdapter = new FRCustomAdapterLatestNews(getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.tab_home_row, R.id.tv_news_date, tempList);

        setListAdapter(newsAdapter);
    }

    private void getNewsDbContent() {
        newsList.clear();
        tempList.clear();
        FRNewsTable getNews = new FRNewsTable(FRNewsList.this);
        newsList = getNews.getNewsFromDB("news_id,headline,detail,submit_date");
        // setNewsList(newsList);
        tempList = newsList;
        getNews.CloseDB();

    }

    public int getDetailId() {
        return detailId;
    }

    public void setDetailId(int detailId) {
        this.detailId = detailId;
    }

}
```

I am not getting the size of my ArrayList as I am using newsList.size() while debugging.
Please review this code and help me out in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please answer to my question, if your listview has all country names, user typed alphabet **A** then, the listview has to display all countries with starting letter **A** or **a**. Yes or No ??

Comment: yes this is what I am trying to do but my ArrayList contains objects and not string.

Comment: I think your procedure may give correct result but its not better way for your requirement. Just check my answer, it may useful temporarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing your code inside `TextChangedListener`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **AutoCompleteTextView** for this requirement. Why you are using ListView ?

The AutoCompleteTextView is designed for this purpose only. Just check the code available at below link you will get an idea about how to use AutoCompleteTextView.

[Example of AutoCompleteTextView](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/example-of-autocompletetextview.html)

Even after visiting the link, you are not able to understand, feel free to ask me.